# react-animated loop becomes very buggy after a short time, React Native, Animated.Text

Tags: javascript, react-native, performance, expo, react-animated

I recently started trying to use animation in an app I am trying to make in React Native.
I am not 100% familiar with React Animated, but I believe the animations that I am trying to make are very simple.

I have a screen where I would like some text to slide in from the right, pause a few seconds, slide out to the left, before repeating itself with some other text.

While I did manage to do that, the animation and the text quickly become very buggy (aka no smooth animation, no animation at all after a while, the text will very quickly change randomly, etc...).

I am not sure why this is, I tried switching the `useNativeDriver` to `true` to hopefully get a smoother animation, but then I get an error saying I can't use the style property 'left'.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function App() {
  let [wordsAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(60)),
    runAnimation = () => {
      wordsAnim.setValue(60);
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(wordsAnim, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 1500,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }),
        Animated.timing(wordsAnim, {
          toValue: -60,
          duration: 1500,
          delay: 3000,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }),
      ]).start(({ finished }) => {
        runAnimation();
        updateWord();
      });
    };

  //An array of random words to display
  const words = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'];

  //First word displayed is a random word from the array
  const [word, changeWord] = useState(
    words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
  );

  //Update the word displayed with another random word from the array
  const updateWord = () => {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    changeWord(words[index]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    runAnimation();
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.Text
        style={{
          margin: 24,
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          textAlign: 'center',
          left: wordsAnim.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 100],
            outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
          }),
        }}>
        {word}
      </Animated.Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

You can also find this example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@oscarp/98962f).

I would also take any tips regarding animations or anything else for React Native,
Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know much about react animation, but I wonder if your `useEffect` might be the problem? As your code is written, `runAnimation` will be retriggered ["after every completed render"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). Perhaps it should only be run on component mount: `useEffect(runAnimation, [])`, or when certain props change: `useEffect(runAnimation, [propName])`?

Comment: Indeed, I have updated the code and added callBacks, works smoothly now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @David784 , my `runAnimation` was retriggered after every completed render. It should've only be run on component mounts.
Adding a few callbacks did the trick!

Working code below:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function App() {
  let [wordsAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(60)),
    runAnimation = useCallback(() => {
      wordsAnim.setValue(60);
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(wordsAnim, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 1500,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }),
        Animated.timing(wordsAnim, {
          toValue: -60,
          duration: 1500,
          delay: 3000,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }),
      ]).start(({ finished }) => {
        updateWord();
        runAnimation();
      });
    }, [updateWord, wordsAnim]);

  //An array of random words to display
  const words = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'];

  //First word displayed is a random word from the array
  const [word, changeWord] = useState(
    words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
  );

  //Update the word displayed with another random word from the array
  const updateWord = useCallback(() => {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    changeWord(words[index]);
  }, [words]);

  useEffect(() => {
    runAnimation();
  }, [runAnimation]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.Text
        style={{
          margin: 24,
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          textAlign: 'center',
          left: wordsAnim.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 100],
            outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
          }),
        }}>
        {word}
      </Animated.Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```